# yarn encore chartist is not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, yarn

Загрузка зависимости не подключила Chartist. Соответственно вызов new Chartist в файле выдает is not defined. Почитал поиск вставил

```
import {Chartist} from 'chartist';
```

теперь выдает что webpack не видит такой импортированный модуль. Как его импортировать в Webpack ну или может совсем иначе нужно было все делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Chartist from 'chartist';
```

Вот так заработало